# Can i use Swift client for SignalR (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, signalr, signalr.client, swiftr

I am developing the new iOS project I need a real-time update from the server so I decided to use **SWiftR** https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR.

I know it is a good package but I have found that it is using **UIWebView** by default and as per Apple, they are going to stop accepting app using UIWebView from April 2020.

Please advise on this should I use it or move to other options like **Socket.io.**

Comment: I am having the same issue. Seem like there is a version of SwiftR library without UIWebViews but I can't connect to the Hub without UIWebView solution. What did you end up doing ?

Comment: I am using this client : https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift